# Train from Belgrade to Bucharest

Tags: trains, romania, serbia, bucharest, belgrade

I'll be visiting Belgrade in April. I'd like to take the train from Belgrade to Bucharest. According to [this little article](http://www.think-railways.com/belgrade-bucharest-international-train-back-service-december/) there is such a train starting from December. Can anyone comfirm this and maybe provide a bit more info?

Comment: I couldn't really find any confirmation with either of the involved railway operators, except for this machine-translated press release on [Yahoo Groups](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/europeanrail/conversations/messages/34913). Europe's international train timetable does change on 14 December every year, but if it really were to be reinstated, I would've expected more details to be available by now. Are you specifically after a direct train? Just asking because you can definitely do the trip with one transfer (in Budapest).

Comment: Regarding the aforementioned timetable changes: [here's an overview](http://www.seat61.com/news.htm), but I don't see any mention of a Belgrade - Bucharest connection.

Comment: @MH: Budapest is a substantial detour and the fastest connection via Budapest is about 24 hours. That is incredibly slow for the 600km from Belgrade to Bucharest, even for East European conditions.

Comment: Both the Serbian and Romanian railways offer online departure and arrival tables one month in advance. If the new train starts on December 14th, it should show up in a couple of days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My experience with Serbian Railways tells me that such a service could be introduced or cancelled without much notice, it'd be a good idea to check in again closer to when you're travelling.

I've emailed [Mr. Popvic at the Wasteels Travel Agency Office](http://wasteels@eunet.rs) in Belgrade station, since he tends to be in the know on such matters. I'll post here if he responds.

I found some info ([here](http://www.drehscheibe-online.de/foren/read.php?30,6407042) and [here](http://www.drehscheibe-online.de/foren/read.php?30,5945808)) on the German railfan site DSO about the alternative train route which requires a few connections, times may change with the new schedule from December:

1. Beograd Dunav Station train [JŽ train](http://w3.srbrail.rs/ZSRedVoznje//direktni/BEOGRAD%20DUNAV/16005/VR%C5%A0AC/21009/27.11.2014/0000/sr) departs 15:50  (train doesn't use main station in Belgrade)
2. 17:35 arrives in Vršac, [CFR](http://www.cfrcalatori.ro/) Trenul Regio train departs 18:40
3. 21:34 arrives in Timisoara Nord Station, CFR 1696 train departs 22:10
4. 7:30 arrives Bucaresti Nord Station

Alternatively you could catch this [Geatours minibus](http://www.geatours.rs/eng/temisvar.htm) to Timisoara and the train onward from there.

Comment: Update: Mr Popvic has responded that the direct train does not exist.